# Extend list class with inplace slicing

Tags: python, list, class, inheritance

I am trying to write a class that inherits from the Python `list` class and has a method that does inplace slicing (original object modified).

This is what I have:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self, mylist = []):
        list.__init__(self)
        self.extend(mylist)
    def slice_it(self, x):
        self = self[:x]
        return self
```

And then I instantiate it:

```
>>> mylist = MyList(mylist=[1,2,3,4,5])
>>> mylist
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> mylist.slice_it(3)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> mylist
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I would expect the last output to be [1, 2, 3]. Any ideas?

Comment: Assigning to `self` just assigns a local variable; like any other variable assignment, it won't mutate your object.

Comment: @user2357112 I know but that was the best I could do. I also tried without that line, but directly with `return self[:x]`. Got the same result.

Comment: If you weren't writing your `MyList` class, and you just had a list you wanted to mutate to produce your desired end state, what code would you write to do that? Write that code in `slice_it`.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea in Python to in-place modify a list, both in terms of convenience and performance.

Comment: @liliscent I dunno, it can be very convenient/efficient in certain cases. I don't know if I would sub-class `list` simply to add a method that does this, but I suspect OP is insisting on some sort of fluent interface.

Answer (score 2):

You are simply *assigning to the local variable `self`*, this won't mutate the list. You have to use a mutator method, so try:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self, mylist = None):
        list.__init__(self)
        if mylist is not None:
            self.extend(mylist)
    def slice_it(self, x):
        self[:] = self[:x]
        return self
```

In action:

```
In [10]: mylist = MyList(mylist=[1,2,3,4,5])

In [11]: mylist
Out[11]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [12]: mylist.slice_it(3)
Out[12]: [1, 2, 3]

In [13]: mylist
Out[13]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Note, you can actually make this work with slice-notation:

```
In [30]: from itertools import islice
    ...: class MyList(list):
    ...:     def __init__(self, mylist = []):
    ...:         list.__init__(self)
    ...:         self.extend(mylist)
    ...:     def __getitem__(self, x):
    ...:         if isinstance(x, slice):
    ...:             self[:] = islice(self, x.start, x.stop, x.step)
    ...:             return self
    ...:         else:
    ...:             return list.__getitem__(self, x)
    ...:

In [31]: mylist = MyList(mylist=range(20))

In [32]: mylist[::2]
Out[32]: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]

In [33]: mylist
Out[33]: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]

In [34]: mylist[0]
Out[34]: 0

In [35]: mylist
Out[35]: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

How's that for a fluent interface?

```
In [36]: mylist = MyList(mylist=range(100))

In [37]: mylist[::2][:10]
Out[37]: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]

In [38]: mylist
Out[38]: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce it *most certainly can be*, especially if you aren't aware of default-argument semantics. I didn't even notice it, to be honest, I just copied from the OP, although, in this case, it might not be so bad, since it is never actually mutated in the `__init__`, but still, probably best to be safe and not use one.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce no need to delete, it's good for people to see these comments. EDIT oh well, too late :)